# Can a Visual Studio extension be downgraded to the previous version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, perforce, p4vs

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and recently updated one of my extensions.  The problem is that the upgrade has broken one of the key extension features and I want to downgrade the version to the previous working release.

Is it possible to see older release versions from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) ?

The extension in question is P4VS (Perforce Version Control).

Comment: You can grab a 13.2 build from our FTP site: http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r13.2/bin.ntx86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Perforce support the FTP site link solved the issue.
I removed the newest version and downgraded and the IDE functionality for submitting is working again.